# usage of ていた in 俺の一撃は、彼のもう一本の剣にギリギリで弾かれていた

Tags: meaning, aspect

I see this kind of thing occasionally, and by that I mean the usage of ていた forms:

> 俺の一撃は、彼のもう一本の剣にギリギリで弾かれ**ていた**

in narrative where the た form:

> 俺の一撃は、彼のもう一本の剣にギリギリで弾かれ**た**

would have meant the same thing to me. What is the difference in meaning/nuance I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

It is the speaker's (or author's) ***temporal viewpoint*** that makes the difference in the tense choices.  More specifically in this case, it is a question of whether one's temporal viewpoint is on the present moment or a time in the past.

***Past tense passive voice*** for a present viewpoint:

> 「[俺]{おれ}の[一撃]{いちげき}は、[彼]{かれ}のもう[一本]{いっぽん}の[剣]{つるぎ}にギリギリで[弾]{はじ}かれ**た**。」
>
> "My shot ***was*** just barely ***repelled*** by his other sword."

***Past perfect passive voice*** for a past viewpoint:

> 「俺の一撃は、彼のもう一本の剣にギリギリで弾かれ**ていた**。」
>
> "My shot ***had*** just barely ***been repelled*** by his other sword."

It would not be very productive to discuss how important the difference is in nuance when all we have is a single sentence.  Generally speaking, the difference in nuance would tend to be relatively minimal unless the larger context proves otherwise.

If the other sentences immediately before or after this sentence were in the pluperfect as well, it would be fairly strange to write this one in the plain past tense.

It is all about the flow.

Comment: My guess is that the past perfect was used to give the nuance of "It all went by very fast, and only afterwards did I realize what had happened, namely that... ". But as you say, hard to be sure without context.

Answer (score 0):

弾かれていた is the past perfect form of the verb: "Had been repelled"
弾かれた is the past form of the verb "Had repelled"